# How to translate the Json in to POJO

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I have the following JSON I need to be able to present in POJO, how could I 
do this ?

The JSON has one key per day and the value for each key is two separate logical arrays, I am using Jackson library.

```
{
  "2014/01/02": [
    {"ABC": 2.25, "XYZ": 4.05},
    {"amazon.com": 3}
  ],
  "2014/01/03": [
    {"ABC": 13.02},
    {"amazon.com": 3}
  ]
}
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using? Jackson? GSON?

Comment: _"and the value for each key is two seperate arrays"_ - No it isn't. Each key maps to a single JSON Array of JSON Objects. You might need to get a better understanding of JSON before you can solve this problem

Comment: I see a `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>`.  I don't see a POJO out of this

Comment: I am using Jackson and I mean its returning two separate logical arrays, I have updated the example JSON snippet above to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have much option. That's an ugly looking JSON. There is no consistent format, where you can create POJO.

Things you need to consider. This `{}` is a JSON object. Im Java mapping terms, it can either map to a POJO, or a `Map`. In order to map to a POJO, you need to common property names and formatting, of which it doesn't seem like you have. It all seems to be varying. So you may need to use a `Map`. Here's how I look at it

```
{  // Start Map
  "2014/01/02": [ // Map key: start Array ( List<Map> )
    {"ABC": 2.25, "XYZ": 4.05},  // Start another Map
    {"amazon.com": 3}  // another Map
```

You can use `@JsonAnySetter` to simplify, using a POJO wrapper, but you will still have, in the end a `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>` as I pointed out in my comment. If you want POJOs, there needs to be some common formatting.

Here's an example of one way to make it work

POJO

```
public class Dynamic {
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Object get(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        map.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Test (using your exact JSON in simple.json file)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Dynamic dynamic = mapper.readValue(new File("simple.json"), Dynamic.class);
        for (String key : dynamic.getMap().keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key: " + key);
            System.out.println("--------");
            List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) dynamic.get(key);
            for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + ", value: " + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("========");
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
key: 2014/01/03
--------
key: ABC, value: 13.02
key: amazon.com, value: 3
========
key: 2014/01/02
--------
key: ABC, value: 2.25
key: XYZ, value: 4.05
key: amazon.com, value: 3
========
```

Comment: You can change the `map` type in the `Dynamic` to `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>` and return `List<Map<String, Object>>` in the `get` method, so you don't need to cast. That's the only improvement I can think of

Comment: nice solution @peeskillet ,but  you should mention here that you have used jackson library.

Comment: @Dev The OP already mentioned they used Jackson (it's tagged as well), and that's what Dropwizard uses by default, so I just assumed it's ok to leave it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
  "2014/01/02": [
    {"ABC": 2.25, "XYZ": 4.05},
    {}
  ],
  "2014/01/03": [
    {"ABC": 13.02},
    {"amazon.com": 3}
  ]
}
This is even JSON, but not useful. I would make JSON for this like below.
{
  [
     {date: '2014/01/01',data:[{abc: 13.02, "amazonCom": 3},{abc: 13.02, "amazonCom": 3}},
     {date: '2014/01/02',data:[{abc: 13.02, "amazonCom": 3},{abc: 13.02, "amazonCom": 3}},
   ]
}

Java
public jsonObj {

    private String date;
    private List<DateData> data;

   .... setter//getter

}

public class DateData {
   private double abc;
   private int amazoneCom;
    //constructor and getter/setter
}



You can use JSON libraries like below.

1. Jackson - http://jackson.codehaus.org/
2. Gson  - https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Those libraries helps you to convert json into Java Object and vise versa as well.

Hope it can help you with solving your problem.
```

Comment: Thats the JSON I get back from an API call.I cannot change it

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to transform json to pojo. Here I am sharing few URL to achieve the same

- **Google Gson Tutorial : Convert Java Object to / from JSON** http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/17/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/
- **Generate Plain Old Java Objects from JSON or JSON-Schema.** http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/